# Resolve And Download Dependency Programmatically - Without Intermediate Ivy File

Tags: java, ivy

I have a method that I use to resolve dependencies using Ivy and return the ResolveReport.

First, here's the code:

```
public static ResolveReport getResolveReport(
            final File cacheFile,
            final SbtDescriptor sbtDescriptor) throws IOException, ParseException {
        final IvySettings ivySettings = new IvySettings();
        final URLResolver centralResolver = new URLResolver();
        centralResolver.setM2compatible(true);
        centralResolver.setName("central");
        centralResolver.addArtifactPattern(ARTIFACT_PATTERN);
        ivySettings.addResolver(centralResolver);
        ivySettings.setDefaultResolver(centralResolver.getName());
        if (Objects.nonNull(cacheFile)) {
            ivySettings.setDefaultCache(cacheFile);
        }

        final Ivy ivy = Ivy.newInstance(ivySettings);
        final File ivyFile = File.createTempFile("ivy", ".xml");

        final DefaultModuleDescriptor md = DefaultModuleDescriptor.newDefaultInstance(ModuleRevisionId.newInstance(
                sbtDescriptor.getGroupId(),
                sbtDescriptor.getArtifactId() + "-caller",
                "working"
        ));
        final DefaultDependencyDescriptor dd = new DefaultDependencyDescriptor(
                md,
                ModuleRevisionId.newInstance(
                        sbtDescriptor.getGroupId(),
                        sbtDescriptor.getArtifactId(),
                        sbtDescriptor.getVersion()
                ),
                false,
                false,
                true
        );
        md.addDependency(dd);

        XmlModuleDescriptorWriter.write(md, ivyFile);
        final String[] confs = new String[]{"default"};
        final ResolveOptions resolveOptions = new ResolveOptions().setConfs(confs);
        resolveOptions.setLog(ResolveOptions.LOG_QUIET);
        final ResolveReport resolveReport = ivy.resolve(ivyFile, resolveOptions);
        FileUtil.delete(ivyFile);
        return resolveReport;
    }
```

To explain, the SbtDescriptor class above is effectively a bean that holds group, artifact and version. FileUtil is just a utility that will delete the temp Ivy file after I'm done with it. I haven't provided the code for those above as you shouldn't need them, but I can upon request add them to the question.

What I'd really LIKE to do is to not have to use an Ivy file at all and simply specify the module descriptor.

However, when I try to change the resolve method above (`ivy.resolve(ivyFile, resolveOptions);`) from using the ivyFile to passing in the module descriptor directly (`ivy.resolve(md, resolveOptions);`), it fails and does not download the required dependent JAR.

Do I have to use the intermediate Ivy file, or is there a way that I can get rid of that part and specific what I want directly via the ModuleDescriptor? If so, how is it done, as I can't grasp the difference in simply writing the module descriptor to an Ivy file and then using it. Why can't I just use the ModuleDescriptor object directly?

Comment: What exactly is your use case? Is using either Gradle or Groovy an option?

Comment: @ThomasHirsch It's difficult to explain. I have an application that I am having to manually download dependencies for in a class that builds the full binary and adds scripts, etc, so that it can then be deployed on a server. Using the intermediate Ivy file is fine and works, but I would really like to omit it so that I don't have that dependency on the file system. I would prefer to specify the dependency I want programmatically only, no file system. And the overloaded resolve method seems to suggest that I can pass the module descriptor directly, but it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This really sounds very much like a use case for a build tool such as Gradle.  It would also allow you to run any Java class as part of your build script. Why do you need to "manually download"? Is it required for this to happen during runtime of your application? Or are you just build the application (sounds like that to me), and then running it somewhere else using the scripts you mentioned?

Comment: The application I'm building the binary for manually resides within a repository which uses an old version of SBT so I can't add a native packager plugin, the way I would within some of our repos here. Therefore, I'm adding the dependencies manually and building up my own binary. This all works fine, but I just want to know if I can omit the intermediate Ivy file or not, as the resolve method seems to suggest that I can, as it has the overload that takes a ModuleDescriptor. My usage of that API doesn't really matter. I just want to know if I can omit the intermediary Ivy file or not.

Comment: And, no, I can't use any other build tool in the repo such as Gradle, etc. All I have is SBT and the version I have is no good to me as it won't build the binary I require hence why i'm just doing it myself as I know all the dependencies that are required.